# The KL-distance in R

Tags: r, integration

I would like to compute the KL-distance from two gamma distribution using R.

[image]

Here is my R-code:

```
theta1 <- 0.2
theta2 <- 2

f <- function(u)
{
     dgamma(u, shape=1/theta1, scale=theta1) * 
      (dgamma(u, shape=1/theta1, scale=theta1, log=TRUE) -
       dgamma(u, shape=1/theta2, scale=theta2, log=TRUE)) 
}

f <- Vectorize(f)
integrate(f, lower=0, upper=Inf)
```

Do you have any comment on my R-code? Do you think it is the good way to compute the KL-distance?

Any suggestion will be appreciated,

Thx,
Marco

Comment: Not sure if it can be useful to you, but there is a `KL.dist` function in the `FNN` package on CRAN : http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/index.html

Comment: I would try my luck at cross validated (mention that you are cross-posting as to not cross some people): http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don't actually need Vectorize, as dgamma already returns a vector result if given vector arguments, and so f does too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define all arguments that are used in the function. What I mean is:

```
my.theta1 <- 0.2
my.theta2 <- 2

f <- function(u, theta1, theta2)
{
     dgamma(u, shape=1/theta1, scale=theta1) * 
      (dgamma(u, shape=1/theta1, scale=theta1, log=TRUE) -
       dgamma(u, shape=1/theta2, scale=theta2, log=TRUE)) 
}


f <- Vectorize(f)
integrate(f, lower=0, upper=Inf, theta1 = my.theta1, theta2 = my.theta2)
```

Being more explicit prevents "accidents", as your function searches `theta1` and `theta2` in higher (global) environments (which can get messy if you have this function buried deep inside a program).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the explicit formula here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Kullback.E2.80.93Leibler_divergence

Comment: Thank you! I am going to compare the result from the explicit formula to my result!